# How to port a firefox extension to google chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, xul

If I create firefox extension, will it run in google chrome also with some changes? I found google chrome extension developing at, http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/ it looks different than XUL. So does that mean these application are not browser compatible? IE would have different language, Am i correct? If all are different then how to develop these three browser compatible application?

Answer (score 1):

Chrome and Firefox now use very similar APIs so porting is not difficult. Mozilla has a great overview of the potential issues here: [Building a cross-browser extension](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Build_a_cross_browser_extension)

Answer (score 0):

There is no XUL support in Google Chrome.

In order to port you extension to different browser you should extract some common part of it, which works solely with web content and does not rely on browser specific features. This part can be shared among extensions (mush the same as you can use jQuery and other libs on all extensions regardless to platform).

The other parts of your extension, including those dealing with UI, must be customized using specific APIs of every browser. For example, for Google Chrome you should use [popup pages](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction.html#ui) or [options pages](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/options.html) for UI. They are HTML+CSS+JavaScript, not XUL.

Comment: Thanks for these link. I will read it. but alas, browser incompatibility is too much developing extension.

Comment: @user2118975, you may have a look at [Kangoo cross-browser extension framework](http://kangoextensions.com/) or similar frameworks.